# Managed memory leak detection - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, memory-leaks

How can I detect managed memory leak in a c# code?
It's about a windowsform application using openGL for rendering 3D objects. Each time I redraw a memory leak is happening.

Base on the analysis done with [DebugDiag tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42933), "C:\Windows\System32\ig75icd32.dll" is the source of memory leak.
Is this a bug in openGL or my code? How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the memory leek source. It was because of opneGL lists.
In a part of my code, I had this code for each 3D object

```
 void UpdateList(){
   _List = Gl.glGenLists(1);
   Gl.glNewList(_List, Gl.GL_COMPILE);
   Polygons.Draw();
   Gl.glEndList();
}
```

Which was in a loop (object's list updating in loop). So many lists were generated for each 3D object and there was many alive objects. I changed the code like this

```
void UpdateList(){
   if(_List==-1)
       _List = Gl.glGenLists(1);
   Gl.glNewList(_List, Gl.GL_COMPILE);
   Polygons.Draw();
   Gl.glEndList();
}
```

So only one list handel is generated for each 3D object.

Comment: have a look at https://snede.net/hunting-net-memory-leaks-with-windbg/ showing how to use WinDbg to find all of the issues